# How to send value to formal parameter to async task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have an async method which invoked by Task.Run. When I send string formal parameter it

```
...
{
   string objectStr = "SomeData";
   ...
   Task t = Task.Run(async () => Sender(objectStr));
   Thread.Sleep(10); /// IF I REMOVE IT, VALUE WILL SAND EMPTY
   objectStr = string.Empty;
}

public async static void Sender(string info)
{
   /// BODY
}
```

Of course, it is wrong to send a variable reference. How I can send an unchangeable value there?

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate the string pass the string to use the `new` operator:

```
{
   string objectStr = "SomeData";
   //...
   Task t = Task.Run(async () => Sender(new String(objectStr.ToCharArray())));
   objectStr = string.Empty;
```

}

This will create a separate copy of the `String`.